# LuaLaTeX for dummies: basic directlua use

Tags: luatex, lua

I'm trying to understand the basics of lua programming within LaTeX.

I have this simple function in a file called `luatest.lua`:

```
function fact (n)
  if n == 0 then
    return 1
  else
    return n * fact(n-1)
  end
end
```

Then I have an usual .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{dofile("luatest.lua")}
\newcommand{\myluafact}[1]{\directlua{function fact(#1)}}  
\begin{document}
  test \myluafact{5}
\end{document}
```

Which unfortunately does not compile. It seems to me that I'm missing some `tex.sprint()` somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The function is called `fact(#1)` without the key word `function`. Also the result needs to be feed back to TeX, e.g. via `tex.write`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{dofile("luatest.lua")}
\newcommand*{\myluafact}[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.write(fact(#1))}%
}
\begin{document}
  test \myluafact{5}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Improvement for `\myluafact`: The lua function `fact` expects a plain integer number, but TeX numbers can come in many different shapes (counters, registers, character constants,  ...). If `#1` is wrapped inside `\numexpr`, then even arithmetic calculations are possible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{dofile("luatest.lua")}
\newcommand*{\myluafact}[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.write(fact(\the\numexpr(#1)\relax))}%
}
\begin{document}
  test \myluafact{\value{page}+2*2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll accept it as soon as they let me. Is there any reason for using the starred version of `newcommand`?

Comment: @AndreasHettel Yes, the argument is a number and should not contain paragraphs (`\par` tokens).