# LuaLatex: Difference between `dofile` and `require` when loading lua files

Tags: luatex

This is a small question related to the answer given here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201742/17858 which computes the factorial of a number in an external lua file.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\directlua{dofile("luatest.lua")}
\directlua{require("luatest.lua")}
\newcommand*{\myluafact}[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.write(fact(#1))}%
}
\begin{document}
  test \myluafact{5}
\end{document}
```

The code for computing factorial is in `luatest.lua` again copied from the same link above

```
function fact (n)
  if n == 0 then
    return 1
  else
    return n * fact(n-1)
  end
end
```

The results from using `dofile` and `require` are identical on my machine for this particular example.

Is there any technical difference between loading external lua files with `require` or `dofile` in general?

Comment: `require` is cached, `dofile` isn't.  Therefore you are guaranteed to always get the same handle of a module from `require`.

Comment: For reference: Same question on SO -> [torch - What are the differences between doFile and require in Lua - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144564/what-are-the-differences-between-dofile-and-require-in-lua#31149198)

Comment: **Note: there's another difference** namely that `require` will look into the "standard search path" instead of just the current directory, so e.g. if you put Lua files in [texmf/commonstuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te?noredirect=1&lq=1) then `require` can find them but `dofile` cannot.  Refer to [luatex - LuaLatex package: \dofile results in error "no such file or directory" - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79216/)

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** `require` is cached, `dofile` isn't.

---

In contrast to `dofile`, `require` caches which files have been requested already.  For example, if you load a module `example`

```lua
local example = require("example")
```

Lua will add the handle that was returned from `example` to an internal table called `package.loaded`.  If your application calls `require("example")` again, Lua will not load the `example` module again, but simply return the handle which was cached in `package.loaded`.

This approach also shows why it is a bad idea to define global variables in a file which is supposed to be used as a module.  The `luatest` module from your question just defines the global name `fact` but does not return a handle.  Therefore the Lua interpreter can't cache it and if something redefines the global name `fact` there is no way to get the original back.  Another issue with global names is, that they tend to collide.  Imagine you had a second module which also defined the `fact` global name.  Which one is Lua supposed to take?

In principle you could use `dofile` for files which you strictly only load once and where all the names defined within are unlikely to collide.  Personally, I prefer modules even for this situation because it reduces interdependencies and makes things reusable in other contexts.

You should restructure your example:

**`luatest.lua`**

```lua
local function fact(n)
  if n == 0 then
    return 1
  else
    return n * fact(n-1)
  end
end

return { fact = fact }
```

**`test.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{luatest = require("luatest")}
\newcommand*{\myluafact}[1]{%
  \directlua{tex.write(luatest.fact(#1))}%
}
\begin{document}
  test \myluafact{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't it the case that (unless you reset the package.loaded table) then `require` won't run the same file twice (if passed the same virtual filename) so even in the OPs original version with `fact` a global name, if you do `require("luatest.lua")` twice then essentially nothing happens on the second call, and if `fact` has been redefined in between the calls that redefinition will be in force as the second `require` will not re-load the definition?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is probably true.  I'd have to read the Lua docs for `package.loaded` again.  My answer is just reconstructed from memory.